# CSS | Как изменять свойства с помощью media

Tags: css, media-queries

На данном этапе изучения media запросов, они умеют только что-то присвоить, но не изменить.
В данном примере изначально у блока голубой фон, хочу что-бы при приближении он становился чёрным. Но ничего не происходит. Поменяется только если изначально не задавать его классу.
Как же это провернуть?

```
<body>
<div class="some-block" style="width: 100px; height: 150px; background: aqua;"></div>
<style>
        @media (max-width:1200px) {
        .some-block {
            background: black;
        }
    }
</style>
</body>
```

Comment: Стили в html-атрибуте `style` имеют более высокий приоритет, чем любые другие стили

Comment: Возможно, но если даже задать их через обращение к классу - это не поможет

Comment: Выше в комментарии написали ведь. Вынесите background: aqua; в css файл тогда заработает.

Comment: Не понимаю... Разве никто не знает о том что уровень приоритета можно увеличить используя `!important`?

Comment: @ΝNL993 многие (в том числе и я) считают его использование плохим тоном

Comment: @andreymal зачастую, чтобы перебить инлайн стили нужно использовать `!important`, тут куда не помещай стили, они выше уровнем по приоритету не станут. Я также стараюсь избегать его использования кроме случая упомянутого ранее, чаще всего хватает того что я просто переношу какой-то стиль в самый низ файла. (Это увеличивает его приоритет среди стилей)